# Patching broken file

Tags: python, django, patch, travis-ci

In my travis setup I want to apply a patch to a very specific python file that is broken on some configurations. The installation procedure looks like this:

```
install:
  # test with various Django versions
  - pip install Django==$DJANGO
  # patch Django 1.4 libgeos
  - 'if [ $DJANGO == "1.4.13" ]; then find . -name libgeos.py  -exec patch {} travis/geos-dev.patch \; ; fi'
```

But apparantly, `find` is not able to retrieve the file in question.

How can I realiably find this file, also across different python versions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple `find` under `/home/travis/virtualenv/` does the job.